# Rails Minitest include to test_helper - uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::TestCase

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I want to add helper from `test/helpers/auth_request_helpers.rb` into `test/test_helper.rb` to have it available in all tests. I thought all I had to do was to include this helper inside of the `test_helper` like below:

```
module ActiveSupport
  class TestCase
    include AuthRequestHelpers
    # some other things
  end
end
```

But when I running a minitest I'm getting an error:

```
uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::TestCase::AuthRequestHelpers (NameError)
```

Did I missed something? I'm not using RSpec

Helper which I tried to add below:

```
module AuthRequestHelpers
  def hmac_code(data, secret_key)
    Base64.strict_encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha256', secret_key, data))
  end
end
```

Comment: `require 'helpers/auth_request_helpers'`

Comment: @max that's what I did, either inside of tested class and `test_helper` and still got `NoMethodError: undefined method hmac_code'`

Comment: try including like this `include ::AuthRequestHelpers`